# Angular - Call functions from external JS library (Bambora Payment Gateway)

Tags: javascript, angular, bambora

I am Integrating Custom Checkout from Bambora in my Angular App.

Here's the doc - https://dev-apac.bambora.com/checkout/guides/custom-checkout/setup

I've been provided this JS libaray which I have added to my **index.html's** head

```
  <script src='https://customcheckout-uat.bambora.net.au/1.0.0/customcheckout.js'></script>
```

Now According to the doc I need to run the followings within the `<script>` tag

```
<script>
var customCheckout = customcheckout();
var cardNumber = customCheckout.create('card-number')
cardNumber.mount('#card-number');
// ...
</script>
```

Here's the codepen example that they've given - https://codepen.io/apac-bambora/pen/bLVXqK/

Now How do I run the above code from my component's .TS file which calls **customCheckout()** method from the script that I added in the  section?

Here's what I've done.

**Index.html** - added the JS library

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CustomCheckout</title>
  <script src='https://customcheckout-uat.bambora.net.au/1.0.0/customcheckout.js'></script>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="checkout-form">
      <div id="card-number"></div>
      <label for="card-number" id="card-number-error"></label>

      <div id="card-cvv"></div>
      <label for="card-cvv" id="card-cvv-error"></label>

      <div id="card-expiry"></div>
      <label for="card-expiry" id="card-expiry-error"></label>

      <input id="pay-button" type="submit" class="btn disabled" value="Pay" disabled="true" />

      <div id="feedback"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var customCheckout: any; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'custom-checkout';

  ngOnInit() {
    customCheckout = new customcheckout();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I configured this was;

in my app.component.ts, I declared

```
declare var customcheckout: any;
```

now this `customcheckout()` is available instantly

so created a new variable and assigned the above method to it

```
  CustomCheckout = customcheckout();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in index.html

```
<script src='https://customcheckout-uat.bambora.net.au/1.0.0/customcheckout.js'></script>
```

Add html/css code in respective component html file and css files

add javascript code as it is in oninit function in required component ts file

Comment: I'v tried that but didnt work. check my updated Question please

Comment: Please add full code like their code sample in ngoninit not only first line and let me know if its still not work

Comment: Added, I just get bunch of errors. even the first line is throwing out error saying "Error: src/app/app.component.ts:12:26 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'customcheckout'"

Comment: can check by replacing customcheckout with customCheckout others are due initializing you can fix it by doing it in typescript way

Comment: yep, but it says "customCheckout is not a function". customcheckout() suppose to be a function in that script, so why change it? and its unable to call that from that <script> tag